# Obtener el valor de un objeto que tenga el nombre de una variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, poo

Tengo un objeto con la ruta en la quer están las páginas, lo que quiero hacer es que al pulsar un botón de un menú cargue esa página, por lo que mi html es este:

```
 <ul>
        <li><a id="home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a id="contacto">CONTACTO</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Tengo un objeto que indica donde están esas páginas:

```
let url = {
home: 'index.html',
about: 'about.html',
contacto: 'contacto.html'}
```

De esta manera si quiero cambiar a donde van los enlaces solo los tengo que cambiar desde el script y no página a página con un `href`

El menú es este:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');

links.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let dest = e.target.id //Si pulsas home esto vale index.html;
        window.history.pushState(null, null, url.dest) // PREGUNTA 1
        $(html).load(url.dest);
    })
})
```

PREGUNTA 1

`url.dest` devuelve `undefined` en lugar de `index.html`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que devuelva `index.html`?

Comment: `url[dest]` en lugar de url.dest

Answer (score 0):

```
links.forEach((item) => {
item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let dest = e.target.id;

    function obtenerEnlace(value)
    {
        return url[value]+'.html' || url['default'];
    }

    window.history.pushState(null, null, obtenerEnlace(dest));
    $('html').load(obtenerEnlace(dest))
   })
})
```

Se arregla así